# Set state of href or passing as props to new component in React

Tags: reactjs, href, state, html5-audio

A bit new to React, so sorry if I don't explain this too well. I'm making a react project that allows users to search for artist tracks from the Spotify API. The search result renders a bunch of cards with artist information, and with a click on an  tag (href is a url to a song preview) I would like to render an audio visualizer component that works with the audio analyzer node and audio tags.

Anyways, I have two main problems:

1) I need to pass the clicked href song preview url to the audio analyzer component as the audio source (something like audio.src = preview_url). I need to figure out how to a) either set the state with the current clicked href and/or b) pass the preview url as props to the audio visualizer component.

2) I need the ArtistCard component to disappear upon clicking the  tag so that only the audio visualizer component is rendered (this will hopefully be easier than question 1).

Here is my code, and sorry again if this doesn't make too much sense. I can try to clarify if need be.

```
export default class ArtistCard extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        renderAudioAnalyzer: false,
        visibility: ''
    }
}

togglePreviewUrlState(){
    this.setState({ renderAudioAnalyzer: true })
    if(this.state.renderAudioAnalyzer){
        this.refs.artistCard.style.display = 'hidden'
        //this currently doesn't work yet...
        // style={{display: 'none'}} <--- do something like this?
    }
}



render() {
    let {tracks} = this.props
    if(!this.state.renderAudioAnalyzer){
        return (
            <div className="card col s3" id="artistCard">
                <div className="card-inner">
                    <div className="card-image">
                        <img alt="/logo.svg" className="Image" src={tracks.album.images[1].url}/>
                        <span className="card-title"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <p id="artistCardTrackName">{tracks.album.name}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-action">
                        <a
                            onClick={this.togglePreviewUrlState.bind(this)}
                            href={tracks.preview_url} //need to set this as state or pass as props?
                        >{tracks.name}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }else{
        return(
            <div><AudioAnalyzer/></div>
        )
    }
}
}
```

and here is the audio visualizer component (obviously missing quite a few things here still but I want to get the href passed over properly before anything else):

```
export default class AudioAnalyzer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div id="mp3_player">
        <div id="audio_box">
          <audio
            refs="audio"
            autoPlay="true"
            controls="true"
            src={this.props.tracks.preview_url} <--href needs to be passed to here some how?
          >
          </audio>
        </div>
        <canvas
          refs="analyser"
          id="analyser"></canvas>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.setState({ renderAudioAnalyzer: true })
if(this.state.renderAudioAnalyzer){
    this.refs.artistCard.style.display = 'hidden'
    //this currently doesn't work yet...
    // style={{display: 'none'}} <--- do something like this?
}
```

setState is async by default, hence after setting state, u cant assume state will be set and do the check `if(this.state.renderAudioAnalyzer)`

Your logic in render function will remove the artist card whenever your click on the ahref. (dont forget to do e.preventDefault, without that it will re render the app again, which is the main problem I think).

And pass the song url to AudioAnalyzer as a prop which is pretty straightforward.